# How can I have 9 objects modify the same value of another class?

Tags: java

So i have 9 objects and they all create a different object each that contains the value I want to modify, but I want all of them to modify the same value so like if object one adds the variable is now two and if object six adds the variable is now three, but I instead modify individually

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PanelClickeable extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    public static final String TXT_VACIO=" ";
    public int X,Y;
    private JLabel etMensaje,etLugar,etBoton,etConteo;
    private JButton botReiniciarConteo,botSalirPrograma;
    private int contadorClicks;
    public PanelClickeable(){
        super();
        valores clicks= new valores();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        addMouseListener(this);
        contadorClicks=clicks.regresarvalor();
        etMensaje = new JLabel("Coordenadas");
        etLugar =  new JLabel(TXT_VACIO);
        etBoton = new JLabel(TXT_VACIO);
        etConteo =  new JLabel(" " );
        JLabel lineaFinal= new JLabel("______________________");
        add(etMensaje);
        add(etLugar);
        add(etBoton);
        add(etConteo);
        add(lineaFinal);
        
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        //etMensaje.setText("("+e.getX()+","+e.getY()+")");
        //contadorClicks++;
        //etConteo.setText("van "+contadorClicks+" clics");
        valores clicks= new valores();
        etMensaje.setText("("+X+","+Y+")");
        clicks.valorinicial(contadorClicks);
        clicks.sumar();
        contadorClicks=clicks.regresarvalor();
        etMensaje.setText(contadorClicks+" :");
        if((contadorClicks%2)==0){
            etConteo.setText("X");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    }

}
```

In this class I am modifying `contadorClicks` and this next class is what i am using to do it:

```
public class valores{
    public int clicksgeneral;
    public void valorinicial(int clicks){
        clicksgeneral=clicks;
    }
    public void sumar(){
        clicksgeneral++;
    }
    public int regresarvalor(){
        return clicksgeneral;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: yes.

You can either make the value you want to modify `static` in your class who's holding the value (`Valores`) or you share the instance of that class (`Valores`) rather than creating a new instance of it every time. The latter one is the cleaner approach in my opinion.

So instead of creating a new instance of `Valores clicks` every time, you can just make it a member of the `PanelClickeable` class.

In the end, you don't even need the `Valores` class at all, since it's basically just a weird wrapper for `contadorClicks`. So instead of creating that instance, you could just modify the values on `contadorClicks` directly.

(Note: Class names in Java are by convention starting with an uppercase letter!)

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem.